# Bindear un adaptador bluetooth a servidor socket

Tags: python, socket, server, bluetooth

La idea es crear un programa simple, que sea capaz de establecer una conexion socket a travez de bluetooth con un dispositivo android(kotlin), para recibir los mensajes que se envian a travez de la app. El codigo que tengo es el siguiente :

```
import socket

hostMACAddress = 'aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff' 
port = 3 
backlog = 1
size = 1024
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_BLUETOOTH, socket.SOCK_STREAM, socket.BTPROTO_RFCOMM)
s.bind((hostMACAddress,port))
s.listen(backlog)
try:
    client, address = s.accept()
    while 1:
        data = client.recv(size)
        if data:
            print(data)
            client.send(data)
except: 
    print("Closing socket") 
    client.close()
    s.close()
```

Cuando voy a ejecutar el programa lo que me encuentro es con el siguiente error:

`OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use`

Lo que no entiendo porque dice que la direccion esta en uso, sera que hay algun subproceso usandolo, en ese caso como puedo hacer para que funcione.

Comment: Cambia el puerto

Comment: Gracias ha funcionado, porque puede ser esto ?

Comment: Algunos puertos están reservados o en uso, por eso se recomienda usar un puerto con un numero alto. Por ejemplo en las PC los primeros 1024 puertos no los puedes usar (o no se recomienda)

Comment: exacto como dice arriba, los puertas hasta el 1024 estan reservados para sistema. no debes usarlos

Comment: se que los protocolos de TCP/IP si pasa esto, en Bluetooth es igual ? . Muchas gracias